# Coinbase pro API returns None on buy order

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am currently making a python auto trading script for coinbase pro. I was wondering if anyone who has experience with the unofficial python library [Library](https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python) can help me out.

```
def attempt_buy(id):
    account_dict = auth_client.get_account(id) #get account info
    balance = round(float(account_dict["balance"]), 2) - 0.01 #get current balance

    if balance > 0:
        result = auth_client.buy(product_id='ETH-USD', order_type='market', funds=balance) #attempt to place buy order
    else:
        result = "Insufficient Balance"

        return result
```

Every time I call this function, it returns `None`. The first time I ran it, it successfully bought the ethereum, then it hasn't at all again.

Comment: `return result` should have one fewer level of indent.

Comment: If control goes to the to the `if` branch then there is no `return` - therefore the method returns `None`